# Bi-directional dynamic_reconfigure

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a few parameters that can be controlled either via dynamic_reconfigure, or via a subscriber, or by updating their value to the state of the hardware they act with.

One direction works well - when I set a value using dynparam or rqt_reconfigure, an action is commanded to the hardware and a parameter update is published automatically.

I want to know if there is a tutorial or at least guideline on how to deal with the other direction - something else (hw event, subscribed message) changes the state and I need the parameters to reflect it.

Obviously, using dynamic_reconfigure.client is not the right way to do it, because it would issue commands instead of just changing parameter values.

So I try publishing directly on `~/parameter_updates` and manually setting the parameter value on the parameter server, which somehow works, but still it seems quite unreliable and cumbersome.

Is there a better way to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217369/bi-directional-dynamic_reconfigure/) by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1366 on 2015-09-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The dynamic reconfigure server has an undocumented `updateConfig` method, which appears to do what you're looking for:  https://github.com/ros/dynamic_reconfigure/blob/4e643b94a2487f6b70b9483e2ea657bc3b6a1030/include/dynamic_reconfigure/server.h#L99

To use it, it looks like you also need to have an external mutex for controlling access to the dynamic_reconfigure config.

Not tested, but this *might* work:

```
boost::recursive_mutex config_mutex;
dynamic_reconfigure::Server<dynamic_tutorials::TutorialsConfig> server;
dynamic_reconfigure::Server<dynamic_tutorials::TutorialsConfig>::CallbackType f;

f = boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2);
server.setCallback(f);

dynamic_tutorials::TutorialsConfig new_config;
server.updateConfig(new_config);
```

Note that the dynamic_recofigure::Server API doesn't require that the mutex be locked before calling `updateConfig`; it does the appropriate locking internally.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2015-09-10**:
Great! I haven't mentioned it, but I looked for a solution in Python. Fortunately, there seems to be a similar method in server.py called `_change_config`. Though it is protected, thanks to Python's liberal object model I think I can call it without hesitation :)

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2015-09-10**:
There is one catch, though. You need to make sure (using e.g. a class-wide flag) that you don't call your API setting stuff again after calling `_change_config`. This way, you'd get into an infinite loop (or a deadlock because of the mutexes). You can also use `update_configuration`, which is public